# Matrix 3d as 2d argument

Tags: java, matrix

I have declared the following:

> int board[][][];

and I have the function:

> boolean compare(int[][] board)

When I use board[][][0], does it become a 2d matrix, right?

If I want to pass my matrix board as argument:

> compare(board[][][0])

, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

A 3d array can be seen as a simple array of 2d array

this is very simple check this example to understand

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
   int board[][][] = new int[10][10][10];       
   board[0][0][0] = 5;

   func(board[0]);      
 }

 private static void func (int [][] tab){

     System.out.println("value : " + tab[0][0]);
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could think of board as an array of 2-d matrices, in which case `board[0]` is a single 2-d matrix, and `board[0][0]` is an array, or perhaps a column of a matrix, and `board[0][0][0]` is an int, or a single cell of a matrix.

And `board[][][0]` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[][][] board;

boolean compare(int[][] board) {
    //implement me
    return false;
}
```

Method call:

```
boolean result = compare(board[0]);
```

You may want another, more flexible solution:

```
boolean compare(int[][][] board, int index0, int index1, int index2) {
    //do check with fixed indices, ignore it if -1 passed - for example
}
```

In case you do not want to pass the whole object, you may just refer it as globally available, however this is not a good practice.

Comment: this works, but I am setting the first dimension as 0. If i want to set the second, as board[][0][], how do I do it?

Comment: I think you cannot pass the object like `board[][0][]` because the 3d array is technically the array, inside which is another array of arrays. If you want to let's say *fixate* second index, try passing three indexes and the whole object to `compare` method. I will update my answer to include an example.